Suspense fallback SSR NextJs 14 at first page loading not working on Safari (on Chrome works)
Having simple Page which contains simple child component like:
import { Suspense } from "react";

async function BlogPosts() {
  let res = await fetch("https://httpbin.org/delay/5", { cache: "no-store" });
  let resjson = await res.json();

  return <div>{resjson.url}</div>;
}

async function Page() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>H E A D E R</h1>
      <div>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>{"fallback  ->  loading..."}</div>}>
          <BlogPosts />
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page;

Try to open page at first time on Safari nothing happened till BlogPosts finish fetching data. Doing the same thing on Chrome there are immediately H E A D E R and loading... visible, then after fetch finished host is displayed instead of loading widget.
Every tutorial in the net tries on Chrome, but not on Safari.
Is there any workaround to fix this thing which broke user's feeling of my page - 2s page loading.

Your loading component must have at least 1kb. Put some text, or SVG, or other stuff.
fallback={<div><_here_must_be_at_least_1kb_></div>}

What exactly is your answer?  That the fallback fails because <_here_must_be_at_least_1kb_> portion was less than 1kb and needs to be more?  Or that it fails because the portion was more than 1kb and needs to be less?  Thanks!
